# Print eval not working to print variable from string

Tags: python, variables, printing, eval

```
class ddx:
  micro = ["iron deficiency (late)", "chronic disease (late)", "thalassemias", "sideroblastic anemia", "lead poisoning"],
  normo = ["normo"],
  macro = ["macro"]

anemiaType = random.choice(["micro", "normo", "macro"])
print eval('ddx.' + anemiaType)
```

Let's say the random.choice is "micro"

I'd like to be able to print ddx.micro

I know I could create a whole bunch of if/else statements to accomplish this, but it seems very clunky/not super readable.

Anyone have any suggestions?

Comment: Why not `print(choice([ddx.micro, ddx.normo, ddx.macro])[0])` ?

Comment: Good thinking! But this is just a snippet of the relevant code - I'm using whether it's micro, normo, or macro to determine a number of things.

Comment: I would suggest avoiding eval since its running string as code with no protection. Instead i would use getattr, to get the attribute safely `print(getattr(ddx, anemiaType))`

Comment: Please read: [Eval really is dangerous](https://nedbatchelder.com/blog/201206/eval_really_is_dangerous.html)

Comment: `getattr(ddx, anemiaType)`

Comment: Interesting. Will update my code!! It's so great learning from experts on here!

Comment: Why not make `ddx` a dict instead of a class?

Comment: @tobias_k I do have dicts in my code, but honestly in this case I figured it would be easier/less confusing to use a class. The dict format can get really confusing, in my opinion.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Nvm I just realized I made the dumbest python 3 mistake of all time - writing `print` instead of `print()`

Answer (score 2):

9 times out of 10 when you want to use eval there is normally a more safe way to do it. Eval will run any arbitrary code so is never a great idea when there are better and more safe ways to do it. In this case you want to access the attribute of a class, so you can use `getattr`

```py
import random

class ddx:
  micro = ["iron deficiency (late)", "chronic disease (late)", "thalassemias", "sideroblastic anemia", "lead poisoning"],
  normo = ["normo"],
  macro = ["macro"]

anemiaType = random.choice(["micro", "normo", "macro"])
print(getattr(ddx, anemiaType))
```

Answer (score 0):

```
import random
class ddx:
  micro = ["iron deficiency (late)", "chronic disease (late)", "thalassemias", "sideroblastic anemia", "lead poisoning"],
  normo = ["normo"],
  macro = ["macro"]
new=ddx()
anemiaType = random.choice(["micro", "normo", "macro"])
#print(anemiaType)
print(eval('new.'+anemiaType))
```

This worked for me